# Regular expression to remove duplicates from comma separated string

Tags: regex, oracle

I have following string:

```
'C,2,1,2,3,1'
```

I need a regular expression to remove duplicates and the result string should be like this:

```
'C,2,1,3'
```

Comment: I'm not sure a regular expression is the way to go here. What have you tried? And what language are you using? (You mention Oracle. Does this mean you're trying to do this in SQL?)

Comment: yes, in SQL select statement

Comment: I suspect this is very difficult in SQL. It would be far easier to retrieve this column and post-process it. If you show us more info and what you have tried this may help (and stop the downvotes).

Comment: So, it seems you want to keep the first occurrence of every token, and discard the second, third etc. - while otherwise keeping the order of the remaining tokens, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input data is more than one string, I assume there is some kind of id column you can use to distinguish the strings from each other. If no such column exists, it can be created in the first factored subquery, for example by using `rownum`.

```
with
     inputs ( id, str ) as (
       select 1, 'C,2,1,2,3,1'   from dual union all
       select 2, 'A,ZZ,3,A,3,ZZ' from dual
     ),
     unwrapped ( id, str, lvl, token ) as (
       select id, str, level, regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)
       from   inputs
       connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(str, ',')
           and prior id = id
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
     ),
     with_rn ( id, str, lvl, token, rn ) as (
       select id, str, lvl, token, row_number() over (partition by id, token order by lvl)
       from   unwrapped
     )
select id, str, listagg(token, ',') within group (order by lvl) as new_str
from   with_rn
where  rn = 1
group by id, str
order by id
;


  ID STR                NEW_STR
---- ------------------ --------------------
   1 C,2,1,2,3,1        C,2,1,3
   2 A,ZZ,3,A,3,ZZ      A,ZZ,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with 
    -- your input data
    t_in as (select 'C,2,1,2,3,1' as s from dual),
    -- your string splitted into a table, a row per list item
    t_split as (
        select (regexp_substr(s,'(\w+)(,|$)',1,rownum,'c',1)) s, 
                level n
        from    t_in
        connect by level <= regexp_count(s,'(\w+)(,|$)') + 1
    ),
    -- this table grouped to obtain distinct values with 
    -- minimum levels for sorting
    t_grouped as (
        select  s, min(n) n from t_split group   by s  
    )
select listagg(s, ',') within group (order by n)
from   t_grouped;
```

Depending on your Oracle version you might have to replace `listagg` with `wm_concat` (it's googlable)

Comment: This ex gives wrong output with "2,CAA,2,1,2,3,1" changing to 'regexp_substr(s,'(\w+)(,|$)',1,rownum,'c',1)' may help

Comment: @Evgeniy K., thanks, it does help. Anyway, the previous syntax worked for me as well.

Comment: Oh, I was blind, sorry. Fixed it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here another shorter solution:

```
select listagg(val, ',') within group(order by min(id))
  from (select rownum as id,
               trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) as val
          from (select 'C,2,1,2,3,1' as str from dual)
        connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
 group by val;
```